# Generate multivariate gaussian and plot them

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I am using the multivariate function from *numpy.random* to generate few clusters. All these clusters, which have the same sigma value, would be plotted in the same graph that has a center point `(x,y)`. I am taking the mean of the clusters to be:

```
x_mean = x_center+v
y_mean = y_center-v
```

Are there any restrictions on what the value of `v` should be to maintain a clear separation between the clusters?

Comment: I don't understand. You've given them the same mean and covariance - they're absolutely going to overlap. What is it exactly that you want?

Comment: @mixedmath: Sorry about my silliness. I interpreted my problem in a wrong way. Editing question.

Comment: Roughly speaking, you would expect that you would need separation at least 3 times the standard deviation for visible distinction, and 5 times to get clear separation.

Comment: @mixedmath: And this standard deviation is the cluster's standard deviation? Because I have a large value for sigma of the clusters = 88 and I have taken the v to be 60 and I still get a clear separation of the clusters. I am just making sure what I have done is right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a different v for each cluster.

Or: generate clusters independently, concatenate the data set. *Shuffle* (to avoid tricking yourself later).